# Some questions about airplay technology license

Tags: airplay

Q:

1. If company wants to develop STB with embedded airplay technology, how to get related airplay technology SDK and apply airplay license (as same as MFi license ?) ?
2. As question 1, What is its license/royalty fee ?

-Frank-

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is not about programming... Try to contact Apple (technology owner) directly, this information probably not-public (NDA may be needed)

Answer (score 1):

You can get a license for creating an AirPlay enabled speaker or other audio device by enrolling in the MFi Program.
But Apple does not publicly license the video streaming part of AirPlay at all.
Apparently Apple is opening up the video licensing somewhat as of 2019 and is now working with some TV manufacturers (Samsung is confirmed, others might follow according to the marketing website for AirPlay) to build AirPlay support into these devices.
There is however no public licensing program in place yet, so if you don't know how to get in touch with Apple about that, you're probably not big enough to get such a license from Apple.

Answer (score -1):

There are Apple's sites about airplay licensing:

- https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/
- https://mfi.apple.com/
- https://developer.apple.com/airplay/

Parts of FAQ https://mfi.apple.com/faqs:

> MFi licensed technology includes: .. AirPlay audio technology
>
> Who should apply to the MFi Program?
>
> Developers who wish to develop electronic accessories for iPhone, iPad or iPod using licensed technology should join the MFi Program. Companies, organizations, government entities and educational institutions are eligible to apply.
>
> There are 2 types of Licenses: a Development License and a Manufacturing License. Companies that plan to develop/help develop, but not manufacture, MFi accessories are eligible for the MFi Development License. Companies that plan to manufacture MFi accessories AND own a manufacturing facility are eligible for the MFi Manufacturing License

Cost is publicly known:

> What is the royalty associated with MFi accessories?
>
> This information is only available under NDA.

Enroll page: https://mfi.apple.com/enroll

Comment: That only covers licensing of AirPlay for Audio devices.  
The OP is obviously looking to get a license for video playback and Apple has no public licensing program for that part of the technology at all at the time of writing this.